# How to constraint a relative layout to take maximum of specified width on screen

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-relativelayout

In my layout file, I have a relative layout and in that layout , I have a textView.
If the text is very large, I want it to take only 60% of the screen and rest of the text will go to new line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSentMsg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="This is sent message"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my layout file and the pictures attached will clarify my doubt.

[image]

as you can see my sent message takes up the whole screen. I want the layout to be aligned to the right and also take up maximum of 60% of the screen.

UPDATE :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/txtSentMsg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7"
        tools:text="Hello, this is a long message and will use other lines as i grows. The default width is 80% of any screen."
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now i have used this and it works. I gives me maximum of 60% screen area But now i can see sometimes, the text view takes up whole of 60 % when contents in it are less.

[image]

As you can see the text how are you is taking up whole 60%. This space goes out when i close the activity and start it again and appears randomly in any message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest usage of linear layout. It is the fastest one, and you could achieve what you want in, on my opinion, easy way:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSentMsg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="This is a very long message that will go in two lines"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are bound to use a Relative Layout, then put the chat rectangles in a relative layout as the below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/chats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/chatInp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But I will recommend you to use Constraint layout as the below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ConstraintLayout`, you can simply tell any view explicitly that how much percentage width or height it should cover with the help of `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent` and `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent`.

Here i will use `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent = 0.8` where 0.8 means 80%.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/textMessage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8"
        tools:text="Hello, this is a long message and will use other lines as i grows. The default width is 80% of any screen."
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I have used your method and it works but now I am getting a new problem check my updated question.

Comment: Use two different layouts one for send messages and one for receive messages. The above code is for send message now for receive message you have to `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent"` and remove `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf`. After that use these two Views in your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ConstraintLayout instead of RelativeLayout and add `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6"` to the child TextView

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7"
        android:background="#637796"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        tools:text="this is my chat message taking 70% of the screen with"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `ConstraintLayout` with a constraint width and constraint the widht percentage to `0.6`:

- `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"`
- `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6"`
- `app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSentMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="This is sent message that can go to up to 60% of the screen width and continue to next lines"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to say only `LinearLayouts` or `RelativeLayouts`. You can combine both and create sectors with specific logics. In my example your parent is `LinearLayout` combined with a `RelativeLayout` and a `LinearLayout` as child Views. As you can see, I simulated a conversation with 2 `TextViews`, one is multilined to expand to exact 60% of the screen and the lower one is only as long as the content provides. To show that both work. I think this is exactly what you wanted. For more clarity I made the left whitespace a greyish solid to see the percentage 40/60 in a better way. Also the `TextViews` are not reaching the bounds because I gave a `10dp` margin for better looking. The technic we are using is called `layout_weight` and `weightSum` provided by the `LinearLayout`.:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#647678"
        android:layout_weight="4">
        <!-- 40% White Space of Screen to left of your RelativeLayout -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- 60% TextView of Screen to right of your LinearLayout -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#304FFE"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="How are you my love? Are you okey, did you have a great day?"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv1"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#304FFE"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Why aren't you responding?"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Result:**

This is the result I came up with:

[image: result]